# When using atom editor screen turns off on UBUNTU 12.04 LTS?

Tags: screen, freeze, 32-bit, editor, atom

Tried installing the editor from Ubuntu software center same things happens(screen turns off), especially when i open settings view. OR If i don't use the opened editor  for sometime and try to type same things happens. I felt like the atom freezes. My system is 32bit . Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Please help?

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the answer. I logged in in safe mode then just changed the ui and syntax theme from one dark to Atom dark. Now atom works fine on Ubuntu Desktop. If you want to use one dark theme you can use Ubuntu-2D Or install Ubuntu 14.04Lts. There it works like a charm.